# SAS 9.4: How to access to specific data in sas file

Tags: sas

I have an SAS file called animals, which contains weight(kg) of animals.

```
dog cat lion human
10   5  200  60
```

How can I slice the data to only animals which have more than 50kg? I want SAS data something like below.

```
lion human
200 60
```

I tried this but did not work..

```
data heavy;
set animals;
if dog--human ge 50;
run;
```

Comment: Is your dataset just one row long?

Comment: Sounds like you have poorly shaped data.

Answer (score 1):

You should transpose it instead.

```
proc transpose data=have
               out=have_flat(rename=(col1=weight) )
               name = animal;
run;

data want_flat;
    set have_flat;
    where weight GE 50;
run;

proc transpose data=want_flat
               out=want(drop=(_NAME_) );
    id animal;
    var weight;
run;
```